# Is $\{v^1+w^1,\cdots,v^k+w^k\}$ linearly independent if $\{v^1,\cdots,v^k\}$ and $\{w^1,\cdots,w^k\}$ are?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\{v^1,\cdots,v^k\}$ and ${w^1,\cdots,w^k\}$ are linearly independent sets in $V$, then is $\{v^1+w^1,\cdots,v^k+w^k\}$ a linearly independent set in $V$?

This may be a basic question but I don't know if this statement is correct or not. Can I get some help?
As far as I can see this statement is not true because it is possible

$$a_1v^1+\cdots+a_kv^k+a_1w^1+\cdots+a_kw^k=0$$

to have another solution rather than all scalars to be $0$, say all $v$ terms are kinda multiple of $w$ terms.
Can I get some thoughts on this?
Thanks

Comment: Please see how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\}$ is linearly independent then so is $\{-v_1,v_2,...,v_k\}$. But $\{0,2v_2,...,2v_k\}$ is not  linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense!